# How to get only X coord of Point

Tags: scripting

As result of `RegionIntersection[]`, I got the `Point` object. Now I want to get it's x coord as a number. How can I do it in Wolfram Mathematica? Tried to use `[[0]]` and searched for documentation, but got nothing.

Comment: try  `[[1,1]]` or `[[1, All,1]]`?

Comment: kgir Thanks, it worked. Can you please post it as an answer so I can approve it

Comment: Goldstein,  I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_]:=If[Length[Dimensions@@x]==1, x[[1,1]],x[[1,All,1]]]
```

Examples:

```
r1 = Circle[{0, 0}, 1];
r2= Circle[{2, 0}, 1];
r3= Circle[{2, 1/2}, 1];

regint12 = RegionIntersection[r1, r2];
regint23 = RegionIntersection[r2, r3];

f @ regint12
```

> 1

```
f @ regint23
```

> {1/4 (8 - Sqrt[15]), 1/4 (8 + Sqrt[15])}